# how to get return values from promise returned from AWS Auth.currentSession()

Tags: javascript, react-native, apollo-client

I am trying to create a graphql client from jwt tokens I can get from AWS.

What I want: the apollo client object defined in the var `ListfulClient`

```
listfulClient ApolloClient {
  "cache": InMemoryCache {
    "addTypename": true,
    "config": Object {
      "addTypename": true,
      "dataIdFromObject": [Function defaultDataIdFromObject],
      "resultCaching": true,
      "typePolicies": Object {},
    },
    "data": Root {
      "canRead": [Function anonymous],
      "data": Object {},
```

what I get: a promise

```
listfulClient Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

It seems that the function `Auth.currentSession()` from the aws amplify library returns a promise. However, I seem to be unable to parse the value to make the apollo client I need. I tried making my function`gqlClient` into an async function but I get the error `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` when I try to use it in gqlClient, even when I made the function async.
Can you please help me out? I have been struggling for several hours on this

```
function gqlClient() {
  // return the promise from currentSession and
  // return the client with token data if
  // the user is logged in
  return Auth.currentSession().then(function(data) {
    // Set the appropriate headers for the environment
    const jwt = data.accessToken.jwtToken;
    const headers = {};
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => ({
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: jwt ? `Bearer ${jwt}` : "",
      },
    }));
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8080/query',
    });
    return new ApolloClient({
      connectToDevTools: true,
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    // something def went wrong
    console.log(err);
    return new ApolloClient({cache: new InMemoryCache(),});
  });
};
```

and I want to create the apollo client, which will be used in my react component

```
function App() {
  // retrieve current session
  var ListfulClient = gqlClient();
  console.log("listfulClient", ListfulClient)
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Arimo_400Regular,
    Arimo_400Regular_Italic,
    Arimo_700Bold,
    Arimo_700Bold_Italic,
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={ListfulClient}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Listful" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={HomeTabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this,
Use an async function for auth link and pass the token from there. And pass that for the client via link.

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/query',
});

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const data = await Auth.currentSession();
  const jwt = data.accessToken.jwtToken;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
       authorization: jwt ? `Bearer ${jwt}` : "",
    },
  };
});

const client=new ApolloClient({
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

In App.js

```
var ListfulClient = client;
```

This will make sure that the token is passed in every request.

Comment: this worked! can you please explain this part of the code, I have no idea what is happening here: ```const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {```

Comment: So basically this would call an asyn function which would be the function to call your getAuth each time a request is sent from the client.